# Finding MLE of the mean and epsilon

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I want to find the MLE of $\mu$ and $\epsilon$, that are the parameters in the density function
$$f(\epsilon,\mu) = (1-\epsilon)\frac{1}{3}e^{x/3}+\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}e^{x/\mu}.$$
I found the likelihood function L,
$$L(\epsilon,\mu) = \Pi_i^n (1-\epsilon)\frac{1}{3}e^{x/3}+\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}e^{x/\mu} = \Big(\frac{1-\epsilon}{3}\Big)^n e^{\sum_i^n x_i/3}+\Big(\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}\Big)^n e^{\sum_i^n x_i/\mu}.$$
I am not sure if my above calculation is correct and what to do next. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, your calculation of likelihood $L$ is incorrect and I doubt that the closed form expression for $L$ exists.

Comment: @NN2 so you are saying, it is impossible to compute by hand this L function?

Comment: The likelihood must be this $\Pi_{i=1}^n ((1-\epsilon)\frac{1}{3}e^{x_i/3}+\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}e^{x_i/\mu})$ and it's not easy to work with.

Comment: @NN2 so how am i supposed to find the estimation of these parameters? :(

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997800/how-to-use-method-of-moments-to-estimate-mean).